# Rolling argmax in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas TimeSeries and would like to apply the argmax function to a rolling window. However, due to casting to float from rolling_apply, if I apply `numpy.argmax()`, I only obtain the index of the slice of the ndarray. Is there a way to apply a rolling argmax to a Series/DataFrame?

`Series.idxmax()` or `Series.argmax()` both return a TimeStamp object but the 
`pandas.rolling_apply(Series, window=10,func=lambda x: pandas.Series(x).idxmax())` will only return float64.

EDIT:
Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2001,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
close = web.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo',start,end).Close
close = close / close.shift(1) - 1

close.resample('W-MON').idxmax()    # Timestamp object
close.resample('W-MON').argmax()    # Timestamp object

pd.rolling_apply(close.resample('W-MON'), window=52, func=lambda x: pd.Series(x).argmax())
```

a working way would be

```
ix = pd.rolling_apply(close, window=52, func=np.argmax)
ix = np.where(np.isnan(ix),0,ix)
ix = ix.astype(int)
new_index = close.index[52:].map(lambda x:     close.index[np.argwhere(close.index==x)-52:np.argwhere(close.index==x)]  [ix[np.argwhere(close.index==x)]])
pd.Series(new_index,index=close.index[52:]).apply(lambda x: x.flatten()[0])
```

but maybe there is some "pandonic" way?

Comment: pls give an example input series here and show your pandas version

Comment: And pandas version is 0.16.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not implemented ATM, but not that difficult, see the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9481)

Here is a work-around, essentially doing the apply 'manually', should be pretty efficient actually.

```
In [59]: rc = close.resample('W-MON')

In [60]: def f(rc, i, l):                                   
    s = rc.iloc[(i*l):((i+1)*l)]
    try:
        return s.loc[[s.idxmax()]]
    except:
        return None
   ....:     

In [61]: pd.concat([ f(rc, i, 52) for i in range(len(rc)) ])
Out[61]: 
Date
2001-06-25    0.034350
2002-02-04    0.017548
2003-05-05    0.031083
2004-10-18    0.044588
2005-05-23    0.022959
                ...   
2011-08-29    0.018310
2012-03-19    0.017339
2013-09-23    0.017571
2014-04-28    0.023196
2015-02-16    0.015051
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Actually what I was looking for was just returning the 's.idxmax()' instead of 's.loc[[s.idxmax()]]'. It takes 1s just for 30 columns with 744 rows =/

Answer (score 2):

Getting rolling argmax of a Pandas dataframe is pretty straightforward only if you use the [Numpy Extensions](https:///github.com/3jane/numpy_ext) library. For example, rolling argmax of a dataframe column of integers with a window size of 3 can be obtained like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from numpy_ext import rolling_apply

def get_argmax (mx):
    return np.argmax(mx)
        

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))

window = 3
df['argmax_rolling3'] = rolling_apply(get_argmax, window, df.A.values)
```

Which will yield a sample output as:

```
    A      argmax_rolling3
0  34              NaN
1  65              NaN
2  65              1.0
3  42              0.0
4  57              0.0
5  30              1.0
6  95              2.0
7  16              1.0
8   7              0.0
9  98              2.0
```