# First occurence with Datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a DateTime indexed data frame called Rolling_Max. It gives the past 2520-day max (price) for each day from 1/1/11 to 1/1/21. How do I add a column to it which has the date each maximum first appeared?

```
dfsp = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^GSPC', start='2011-01-01', end='2021-01-01')['Adj Close']
window = 2520
Roll_Max = dfsp.rolling(window, min_periods=1).max()
```

[The second row should have another column saying "2011-01-03"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI0Zw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling argmax in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391787/rolling-argmax-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming price is a pd.Series

```
price_argmax = price.reset_index(drop=True).rolling(2520, min_periods=130).apply(lambda x: x.index[x.argmax()])
price_argmax = pd.Series(price.index[price_argmax.dropna().astype("int")], index = price.index[price_argmax.dropna().index]).reindex(price.index)
```

If you need this to be fast then you might want to write a loop with numba/numpy.